# SystemSoundID Sometimes Changing With Device Volume

Tags: iphone, ios, audio, system, volume

I am playing sound effects in my game using the `SystemSoundID` class, with some odd results. A few of my sounds, including `landed1` below, change volume according to the volume buttons, but others, like `deathsound` always play at full volume. Below is all code related to the two sounds.

```
SystemSoundID deathsound;

SystemSoundID landed1;
```

...

> NSURL *soundURL;

```
soundURL = [[NSBundle mainBundle] URLForResource:@"SMPKLanded1" withExtension:@"mp3"];
    AudioServicesCreateSystemSoundID ((__bridge CFURLRef) soundURL, &landed1);

soundURL = [[NSBundle mainBundle] URLForResource:@"SMPKDeathSound" withExtension:@"mp3"];
    AudioServicesCreateSystemSoundID ((__bridge CFURLRef) soundURL, &deathsound);
```

...

```
AudioServicesPlaySystemSound(landed1);
```

...

```
AudioServicesPlaySystemSound(deathsound);
```

Why would the two act so differently, if the code and filetype are essentially the same? It makes no sense!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I finally figured it out, after inordinate amounts of time driving myself crazy. Some of them are being played at the same time as an `AVAudioPlayer`, which for some reason made them conform to the volume buttons, and some weren't. My obvious next step would be to make a silent `AVAudioPlayer`, which I have now done, and the program works as I would expect.

As a follow up question, does anybody have any clue why having an `AVAudioPlayer` affects `SystemSoundIDs`?